# How to use ultimate thread group plugin in JMeter, which is executed from an Azure Devops pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, jmeter, azure-pipelines, jmeter-plugins

I have an ADO pipeline which starts a JMeter script execution on a VM(load-generator) using a Command Line task. Following is the command line statement -

```
C:\JMeter\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\bin\jmeter -n -f -t "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\JMeterTestScripts\$(Module)\$(TestName).jmx" -l "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\$(TestName).jtl"
```

I am using the ultimate thread group for one of my test scripts.
The JMeter executable folder on the VM has all the necessary plugin-related JARs present in the lib/ext folder. But for some reason while trying to run this pipeline, it throws the following error-

```
*An error occurred: Error in NonGUIDriver Problem loading XML from:'C:\agent\_work\1\s\Jmeter_Script_Folder\ScriptName.jmx  Cause:
CannotResolveClassException: kg.apc.jmeter.threads.UltimateThreadGroup*
```

However, when I try to execute the same command from the VM (load generator) manually using the windows cmd, then it successfully triggers the test execution.

Any idea, what possibly could be causing this odd behaviour? Any pointers on this is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, how do you register the self-host agent? Do you run that agent in interactive or service mode?

Comment: It is started as a windows service.

Comment: Try installing a new agent with interactive mode, disable the service mode one and enable the interactive one, run the pipeline again to check if it helps.